# parsing url links into a list

Tags: python, scrapy

I have made a spider using scrapy and I am trying to save download links into a (python) list, so I can later call a list entry using `downloadlist[1]`.

But scrapy saves the urls as items instead of as a list. Is there a way to append each url into a list?

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


DOMAIN = 'some-domain.com'
URL = 'http://' +str(DOMAIN) 


linklist = []

class subtitles(scrapy.Spider):
    name = DOMAIN
    allowed_domains = [DOMAIN]
    start_urls = [
        URL
    ]

# First parse returns all the links of the website and feeds them to parse2 

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
                url= URL + url 
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse2)

# Second parse selects only the links that contains download

    def parse2(self, response): 
        le = LinkExtractor(allow=("download"))
        for link in le.extract_links(response):
            yield Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse2)
            print link.url

# prints list of urls, 'downloadlist' should be a list but isn't. 

downloadlist = subtitles()
print downloadlist
```

Comment: If `downloadlist` isn't a list, what is it?

Comment: I think it could be a request object, according to the scrapy documentation. When I try to print `downloadlist[3]` I get: TypeError, 'subtitles' object does not support indexing.

Comment: why don't you pass  `downloadlist` as an argument and then append elements to it wherever you need.

Comment: You don't need to use `HtmlXPathSelector`, you can call you xpaths directly on response: `response.xpath("some_xpath")`. Also don't use `URL + url`, you can use `response.url.join("some_relative_path"))` to create absolute path from a relative one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how classes work, you are calling a class here not a function.

Think about it this way, your spider tht you define in `class MySpider(Spider)` is a template that is used by scrapy engine; when you start `scrapy crawl myspider` scrapy starts up an engine and reads your template to create an object that will be used to process various responses.

So your idea here can be simply translated to:

```
def parse2(self, response): 
    le = LinkExtractor(allow=("download"))
    for link in le.extract_links(response):
            yield {'url': link.urk}
```

If you call this with `scrapy crawl myspider -o items.json` you'll get all of the download links in json format.
There no reason to save downloads of to a list since it will be no longer of this spider template (class) that you wrote up and essentially it will have no purpose.

Comment: thank you, yes this is how I have been working with it form the terminal. But  I would like to access one random url from the list it creates. So I thought it would be better to implement this my subtitles.py script. Or would it be better to write a second script that selects a random url from the json file?

Comment: @LuukS yes - it would be smarter to split these logics and write a script for whatever you want to do with the json value you get from the pider. This way you can crawl once and then do whatever you want with your list as many times as you want.

Comment: Thanks, that is how I will do it!